# Alterar fonte TextView

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estou tendo problemas ao alterar a fonte do TextView em meu projeto, já tentei todos os métodos encontrados na internet e nenhum alterou. Sem erros no debug e sem erros ao abrir o app.
Estou usando a linguagem Kotlin.

**Informações**

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion 15
```

Minha primeira tentativa foi criar um repositório **font** e colocar a fonte dentro do mesmo, logo em seguida alterar o **android:fontFamily="@font/customfont"**. Sem sucesso.

Segunda tentativa foi utilizar programação junto com **assets/fonts/customfont.ttf**

```
textLogo.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/customfont.ttf")
```

Sem sucesso também. Já não sei mais o que fazer.
**Outra fonte funciona normalmente.**

Ao abrir o arquivo **.ttf** da fonte ocorre o seguinte erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com essa exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TextHitInfo is out of range
at java.awt.font.TextLayout.checkTextHit(TextLayout.java:780)
at java.awt.font.TextLayout.getCaretInfo(TextLayout.java:1220)
at java.awt.font.TextLayout.getCaretInfo(TextLayout.java:1322)
at javax.swing.text.GlyphPainter2.getSpan(GlyphPainter2.java:82)
at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getPartialSpan(GlyphView.java:330)
at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getMinimumSpan(GlyphView.java:557)
at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(ParagraphView.java:725)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextAreaUI$PlainParagraph.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BasicTextAreaUI.java:272)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(BoxView.java:568)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BoxView.java:903)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(BoxView.java:343)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(BoxView.java:708)
at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(BoxView.java:397)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(BasicTextUI.java:1769)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.modelToView(BasicTextUI.java:1072)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.modelToView(BasicTextUI.java:1050)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.repaintNewCaret(DefaultCaret.java:1308)
at javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret$1.run(DefaultCaret.java:1287)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:757)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:706)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:375)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sempre post o código. Como você está tentando? Algo assim resolveria:

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(Rep.id.android_text) as TextView
textView.setOnClickListener {
textView.text = getString(Rep.string.name)
}
```

Comment: Estou apenas tentando alterar a fonte, mas a fonte que eu gostei está apresentando erros. Outras fontes funcionam não sei porque. Com outra fonte isso resolveu `app:fontFamily="@font/modernia`, mas com a fonte que eu gostei nada resolve.